# How to implement a hotel room pickup app?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django app which would take data on the numbers of rooms sold in a hotel for each (future) date, on any given date, and use that data to determine pickup rate. For example, this is what the data for 12/22/2021 might look like:

| Date | Rooms Sold | Days Prior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/23/2021 | 34 | 1 |
| 12/24/2021 | 19 | 2 |
| 12/25/2021 | 11 | 3 |
| 12/26/2021 | 10 | 4 |
| 12/27/2021 | 3 | 5 |

So on 12/22, the hotel had 34 rooms sold for the night of 12/23, 10 rooms sold for the night of 12/26, and so on. My goal for this app is to compare how the numbers are changing to determine the pickup rate for a given date. For example, if on 12/25 the hotel had 20 rooms sold for the night of 12/26, then I would be able to see that the pickup for that date/night was 10 rooms over the course of 3 days (because there was 10 rooms sold on 12/22). I would want dates to get flagged if there was a sudden pickup in rooms sold on that date, signaling a possible event and increase in demand for rooms that day.

I'm just having trouble figuring out how I should do this with Django. The best thing I can think of is to create a Date model, with a different instance for each date, and each instance would have a dictionary keeping track of the "rooms sold" history for that date, with the "key" being the "days prior" column, and the "value" being the "rooms sold" column, so something like this:

```
# This would be for the room night 12/26, indicating that 4 days prior to 12/26 we had 10 rooms sold, and 1 day prior we had 20 rooms sold
{4: 10,
 1: 20}
```

But it seems like I have to put everything in model fields, not as a plain old dictionary which would be an attribute of each date instance. How could I go about this? I'm assuming maybe something with ForeignKey, but would that mean I would need to create a separate model instance for each data point per date? I really don't know how to proceed with this.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I hope I made some sense. Thank you!

Comment: I just realized maybe I can make a TextField object containing the data in a format like `4,8:3,15:2,19:1,36` that I can extract? Would this be problematic or inefficient

Comment: Hey! How do you plan for the data (new room sells) to get to your application? Is this for real world use or some kind of assignment?

Comment: This is for real world use. I have written a Python module/function that takes the PDF report data from the hotel software and exports it into a dictionary format. So I would need to append existing "Business Date" model instances' "pickup history" each time new data is imported

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the data - aren't you duplicating it in every date? For example, the data would look the same for 12/23/2021, except the first row is missing and "days prior" is increased by 1?

Comment: The "Rooms Sold" column would also be different - because this is showing how many rooms are sold for a night for a given date, i.e. how many reservations we have in our system, but as new reservations are booked that number will go up with each new report. I'm trying to look at the rate of this increase